# Cannot size a table in a div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fLagG/

Look above at my Jfiddle

My problem is that I cannot set the dimensions of my table that is in a div. I want to adjust the size of the table and if it is larger than the div, it should overflow and a scroll bar should appear. After hours of work I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?
Thank you.

**CSS**:

```
.class {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    padding: .2em 0 .2em .5em;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: 000000;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#e3e3e3), color-stop(.6, #B3B3B3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6, #B0B0B0, #B3B3B3 90%);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    width: 400px !important;
}
.classTD {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-color: 000000;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f2f2f2), to(#e3e3e3), color-stop(.6, #B3B3B3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D6D6D6, #e3e3e3, #D6D6D6 100%);
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    width: 400px important;
}
#Pallate {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
#Scroll_Table_Border {
    Position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    Left: 320px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 850px;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
#Scroll_Table {
    left: 25px;
    top: 15px;
    Position: Absolute;
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ID = "Pallate">
    <div ID = "Scroll_Table_Border">
        <div ID = "Scroll_Table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class = "class">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                    <td class = "classTD">Row 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? 
http://jsfiddle.net/BLnLC/

**HTML:**

```
<div ID = "Pallate">
    <div ID = "Scroll_Table_Border">
        <div ID = "Scroll_Table">
            <table ID="table1">
                <tr><td class = "class">Row 1...
```

**Added CSS:**

```
#table1
{
  width:1000px;  
}
```

Comment: Well that is close but I still cannot make the columns very wide. I believe that is because the table overflows out of the parent div and thus is automatically resized. I need to have wide columns because sometimes the cells contain allot of text. I still cannot make the cells very wide with this

Comment: In your .class try changing "width:400px !important;" to min-width:400px;

Calling the !Important will force the cell width to always be 400px wide. Changing it to min-width will force it to not fall below that size and allow it to grow.

Answer (score 0):

I have just added the below css code to [your jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fLagG/2/) and scroll bar appears for table.

```
table{
    width: 1500px;   
}
```

Comment: Also, you can try not to create those additional divs for border & scroll table classes. You can achieve the same by just using table's css properties.